# Smart replacement of missing fonts

Tags: fonts, xetex

The [Open Sans Condensed](https://www.google.com/fonts/specimen/Open+Sans+Condensed) fonts only have **Bold** and not ***Bold italic***, so when I use

```
\setmainfont{Open Sans Condensed Bold}
```

and then try to use `\textit{Foo}`, it doesn't render it in italic, since there isn't a font for it. However, I've noticed that for some purposes, I can use Open Sans Condensed *Light Italic* with a `\textbf` applied to it.

Is there a way to either

- change font midway (cumbersome if I need to do it in several places)
- tell XeTeX to "smartly" substitute all occurrences of `\textit` for the above main font with my preferred alternative (convenient to use)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't have an Open Sans Condensed Bold font, but the theory is just the same:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
  ItalicFont={Open Sans Condensed Light Italic},
  ItalicFeatures={FakeBold=6}]
  {Open Sans Semibold}

\begin{document}
This is normal text and \emph{this should be slanted}
\end{document}
```

I used Open Sans Semibold as the main font, so the result is not nice, but should be self-explanatory.

[image]